# how reach class name (Styled Component)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

class = "ScrollbarLayout_main ScrollbarLayout_mainVertical public_Scrollbar_main"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goxwZ.png)

```
   export const Root = styled.div`
      && {
        .ScrollbarLayout_main {
          && {
            .ScrollbarLayout_mainVertical {
              && {
                .public_Scrollbar_main {
                  top: 0;
                }
              }
            }
          }
    }
`
```

i want to remove top

Comment: could you have a go explaining your issue in a bit more detail please?

Comment: see image please . i want to remove - top : 100px

Answer (score 0):

To override styles in your app that were created outside of Styled Components, you can use `createGlobalStyle` (explained [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle)).

Don't forget to add the `GlobalStyle` component to the top-level of your project.